# Add .jar dependency to Java Library Module Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create a Java library in Android Studio. I want to use functionality of another Java library (third party available as a .jar) in it. So I placed the library in `libs` folder of my java library project and added the following code in `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
dependencies { 
    implementation files('libs/libraryname.jar')
}
```

The .jar reference was added successfully and I can use the library methods in my code. My project also compiles successfully and I am able to generate a .jar file of my own java library project.

However, when I am using the generated .jar file in another project and try to access the methods of third party library, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.packagename.classname" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.packagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]

**What I have tried**

I have tried multiple solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281734/libgdx-transitive-dependencies-android-java-library-project-jar) but none of them works.

I have tried to clean and re-build the project and .jar files as well but that doesn't help as well.

I have added the .jar dependency as a module before referring it in my project but it still generates the same error.

**Note:**

I am using **Android Studio 3.1.4**

Comment: Can you iport it from setting? Can I tell you about this way?

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano Sure! why not? which settings?

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano If you are talking about Settings > Project Structure, then i have already tried it.

Comment: Yes I told about Project Structure -> Libraries -> Dependencies or also you can import it in other way.. I'll answer your question with this method

Comment: Please rate my answer if'd help you

Comment: Are your class public? are you importing the library in a second android studio project? Did you have imported the libray in the same way that you have import the first library?

Comment: yes classes are public. Yes I am importing the library in a second project in the same way as i did in the first library

Comment: Ok tomorrow I will ask you more details if you haven’t find a soluction

Comment: Did you find solution for this @Jordan?

Comment: No I haven't found any solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copy .jar in your libs project folder: change the navigator to **project** view, than you are able to see libs directory.
Right click on your jar folder inside your project and select *add as library*, this will automatically import the library on your gradle dependencies

Comment: In android studio 3.1.4 add as a library option is not shown when i right click the .jar file.

Comment: Probably is already added in project,, can you check on your project Structure -> libraries if the library is present?

Comment: Yes it is present.

Comment: So the problem that you have is not in importing the library

Comment: can you check if the library that you are importing correctly? try to decompile it t see his method reference

Comment: I am able to call the library methods in my JAVA library code. The issue arises when I compile it and use the generated .jar file in another project.

Comment: Please refer to my question again